# Ordering with awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I have find out awesome_nested_set is the most popular Rails gem for making categories tree. Unfortunately, it hasn't categories ordering function or it isn't docummented.

Maybe anyone knows how to change these categories order?

```
Menu
  - about
  - first page
  - second page 
  - contacts
```

I don't know how to to add some new categories in the middle of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that the node called `first page` is an instance of the model Page and has the ID 3. You can do the following:

```
first_page = Page.find(3)
new_page = Page.create(:name => 'new page')
new_page.move_to first_page, :right
```

This will create a new page called `new page` and put it between `first page` and `second page`.

**EDIT**: after looking at the [code](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/707dbec95c5c759cec2460ea29face53c11568f2/lib/awesome_nested_set/model/movable.rb), it appears that there is now also a method `move_to_right_of`, which might be more convenient.